# Dynamic GUI Creation from ResultSet - Java

Tags: java, mysql, swing, resultset

I'm trying to create a Java GUI dynamically by taking values from a result set and using it to generate a checklist. I've created a small demo program to demonstrate what I've done:

**SQL Commands**

```
CREATE USER 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'testpw';
CREATE DATABASE combotest;
USE combotest;

CREATE TABLE combotable (
id INT(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
type VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO combotable (id, type) VALUES
(default, 'Label'),
(default, 'Textfield'),
(default, 'Combo'),
(default, 'Label'),
(default, 'Textfield'),
(default, 'Combo'),
(default, 'Combo');

GRANT SELECT ON combotest.* TO 'test'@'localhost';
```

For your convenience if you'd like to test it yourself I've put all the SQL commands above.

Now, for my Java code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.*;  
import javax.swing.*;

public class resToComboDemo implements ActionListener {

//JDBC Variables
static Connection connect = null;
static Statement statement = null;
static ResultSet res = null;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
//Other Variables
JComboBox comboBox;
JButton submit;
JFrame frame;
JLabel label;
JTextField textField;
Container pane;

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    new resToComboDemo();
}

public resToComboDemo() throws SQLException {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        // Setup the connection with the DB

        connect = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/combotest?"
                        + "user=test&password=testpw");

        statement = connect.createStatement();
        //Note: in this specific case I do realize that "order by id" is not necessary. I want it there, though.
        res = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM combotable ORDER BY id");

        createStuff(res);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error 1: "+e, "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } finally {
        connect.close();
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked" })
public void createStuff (ResultSet res) throws SQLException {

    frame = new JFrame("Testing dynamic gui");
    Dimension sD = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int width = sD.width;
    int height = sD.height - 45;
    frame.setSize(width,height);

    pane = frame.getContentPane();

    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));

    while (res.next()) {
        Object[] options = { "Pass", "Fail"};
        String type = res.getString("type");

        JLabel label = new JLabel("<html><small>"+type+"</small></html>");
        JLabel blank = new JLabel(" ");
        blank.setBackground(Color.black);
        blank.setOpaque(true);

        if (type.equals("Label")) {
            label.setBackground(Color.black);
            label.setForeground(Color.white);
            label.setOpaque(true);
            pane.add(label);
            pane.add(blank);

        } else if (type.equals("Combo")) {
            pane.add(label);
            comboBox = new JComboBox(options);
            pane.add(comboBox);

        } else if (type.equals("Textfield")) {
            pane.add(label);
            textField = new JTextField(20);
            pane.add(textField);

        }   
    }

     JLabel blank2 = new JLabel(" ");
     pane.add(blank2);

     submit = new JButton("Submit");
     submit.addActionListener(this);
     pane.add(submit);

     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setVisible(true);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

}
}
```

Now, everything works great with creating the GUI here. However, I need to be able to treat the Combobox and Textfield components as their own separate entities. Meaning, I want to be able to get user input from each different component. Right now, if I were to request information from textfield, it just gives me the information from the last textfield. This makes perfect since, because that's how java reads it. I have no problem with that.

I just can't for the life of me figure out how to get each component's input separately. Perhaps by taking the result set and adding the results to some type of array?  I've attempted this multiple times in different flavors and I can't get it to come out the way I need it to. Some of you are going to request that I show you what I've tried... but honestly, it's not worth it.

And, before anybody asks: No, I will not use FlowLayout. :)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why didn't keeping them in an array or list work? I would also recommend fixing warnings instead of suppressing them.

Comment: The answer depends. Do you care about the record `id`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, yes, the ID is relevant because I may require the items be in a certain order.

Comment: @MikeB in regards to keeping them in an array... I could get it to dump out fine (create the GUI) but I couldn't figure out how to get the input of each individual GUI element.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a few ways to achieve this based on what you want to do...

If you are only performing a batch update, you could use a `Map` keyed to the `id` of the row and mapping to the `Component`.

This way, when you want to save the values back to the database, you would simply iterate the `Map`s key values, extract the `Component` associated with each key and then extract the value of the `Component`...

I might consider making a wrapper `interface` which has a simple `getText` method and wrap the component within it, making the implementation of the wrapper responsible for extracting the text, but that's just me ;)

If you want to perform updates when a individual component is updated, you would need to swap the mapping, so that the `Component` would the key and the `id` would be mapped to it.

This would mean that when some kind of event occurred that would trigger and update (ie a `ActionEvent`), you could extract the `source` from the event and look up the `id` in the `Map` based on the `Component` that caused the event...

Now...frankly, I would simply use a `JTable` and create a custom `TableModel` which could model all this.

This would require you to create POJO of the table, maintaining the `id`, `type` and `value` within a single object.  This would define a basic row in the table.

The only problem is you would need to create a (reasonably) complex `TableCellEditor` that could take the `type` and return an appropriate editor for the table.  Not impossible, it's just an additional complexity beyond the normal usage of a table.

This would all the information you need is available in a single object of a single row in the table.

Take a look at [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Equally, you could use a similarly idea with the `Map` ideas above...

You could also simply create a self contained "editor" (extending from something like `JPanel`), which maintain information about the `id` and `type` and from which you could extract the value and simply keep a list of these....for example...

Comment: Thank you for taking the time on this detailed answer! It helps a lot in seeing different options. However, perhaps I failed to explain what exactly I'm requiring from my program. It's rather simple. Say you have a checklist, and this checklist has two items in it. Each of them requiring a dropdown box for Pass/Fail. Consider this for an example: 1. It's raining outside. (It's put in the database as a Combobox) - The java code gets it's title (It's raining...) and creates the JLabel. Then creates the Combobox. 2. It's hot outside. Same as above. However, I need to check both combo.

Comment: Then, use a `Map` to map the `id` to a `component`.  Iterate over the `Map`, getting the `id` and `component` check all the components

Answer (score 0):

You only have a reference to the last text field or combo box that you create, since you are reusing the variables that hold them.  I would put them in an ArrayList, store each new text field and combbox as you create them, then you can go back and get input from all of them after you're done.

---------- (after the OP's response to the above paragraph)

No, there is no "place to refer you" -- it's your set of requirements, it would be pretty remarkable to find code that already existed that did this exact thing.  Java and Swing give you the tools, you need to put things together yourself.

You don't show your "actionPerformed" routine, but let's hypothesize about it for a minute.  It is called by the framework when an action is done, and it is passed an "ActionEvent" object.  Looking through its methods, we find that it has "getSource()", so it will give you a reference to the component which generated the event.

Let's further think about what we have -- a set of components in the UI, and ones which can generate events are interesting to us.  We want to, in this case, retrieve something from the component that generated the event.

If we have the component (from actionEvent.getSource()) and we want to do something with it, then we can, at worst do something like the following in the actionPerformed() method:

```
Component sourceComponent = actionEvent.getSource();
if (sourceComponent instanceof JComboBox)
  { JComboBox sourceBox = (JComboBox) sourceComponent;
    // get the value from the combo box here
  }
else if (sourceComponent instanceof JTextField)
  { JTextField sourceTextField = (JTextField) sourceComponent;
    // get the value from the text field here
  }
// or else do nothing -- our action was not one of these.
```

Done this way, you don't even need to keep a list of the components -- the UI is keeping a reference to all of them, and you just use that reference when the actionEvent occurs.

Now, this is not the only or even the best or the simplest way of doing this.  If you wanted to extend JComboBox and JTextField with your own classes, you could have those classes both implement an interface that defined something like `getValue()` or `getText`; then you would not need the ugly `instance of` operator, which can usually be done away with by better design and planning.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not sure how to do this the correct way, then. As I've said: this is the obvious solution, but whenever I've tried it it just... didn't work for me. Can you point me to somewhere I can reference for something like this perhaps? If you can I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

what about interrogating the Container ( pane) which contains the components 
getComponents() method and loop through the sub component and check for JComobox and JTextField  do the required cast and retrieve the value

Just an idea in case you are against adding the sub-components into a kind of list